# como generar arreglo de registro de manera aleatoria?

Tags: c

yo defini el siguinete tipo de registro

```
void cargar_alumno(t_alumno* alumno) {
    printf("Ingrese datos del alumno\n\n");

    printf ("Legajo: " );
    scanf("%d", &(*alumno).legajo);
    while (getchar() != '\n'); /* Limpieza buffer de teclado */

    printf("Nombre: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets((*alumno).nombre,30,stdin);
    if ((*alumno).nombre[strlen((*alumno).nombre)-1] == '\n')
    (*alumno).nombre[strlen((*alumno).nombre)-1] = '\0';
    else
    while (getchar() != '\n'); /* Limpieza buffer de teclado */

    printf("Apellido: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets((*alumno).apellido,30,stdin);
    if ((*alumno).apellido[strlen((*alumno).apellido)-1] == '\n')
    (*alumno).apellido[strlen((*alumno).apellido)-1] = '\0';
    else
    while (getchar() != '\n'); /* Limpieza buffer de teclado */

    printf ("Nota 1: " );
    scanf("%d", &(*alumno).nota1);
    while (getchar() != '\n'); /* Limpieza buffer de teclado */

    printf ("Nota 2: " );
    scanf("%d", &(*alumno).nota2);
    while (getchar() != '\n'); /* Limpieza buffer de teclado */

    printf ("Nota 3: " );
    scanf("%d", &(*alumno).nota3);
    while (getchar() != '\n'); /* Limpieza buffer de teclado */
    

 }
```

pero a la hora de cargarlo lo hago manualmente y yo quiero que sea de manera aleatoria
por eso quisiera saber cual es la manera de hacerlo.

esta es la consigna: Escribir un procedimiento que almacene en un arreglo de registros
los datos de 10 alumnos, conteniendo su legajo, nombre, apellido y las calificaciones de los 3
exámenes parciales de una asignatura.

Comment: Sugerencia: Puedes usar `->` para acceder a la variable de un puntero. Por ejemplo `alumno->legajo`. `&(*alumno).legajo` se convertiría en `&alumno->legajo`.

Comment: Por cierto, no me queda claro el problema/la pregunta. ¿Podrías explicarte mejor?

Comment: mi pregunta era para no poner por ejemplo nombre = juan por teclado que los nombres apellidos y demas datos se carguen de manera aleatoria no por teclado